# Uso de variável local não atribuída. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

Estou desenvolvendo um site que faz uma requisição a uma api e mostra os dados para os usuários, porém estou com problemas:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'value'

> Use of unassigned local variable 'date'

Para entender melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da página com o erro:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    public Global Global { get; private set; }
    public Country[] Countries { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public IMemoryCache MemoryCache { get; private set; }
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
      _logger = logger;
      MemoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
      try
      {
        string key_countries = "countries_cache"; // Chave do cache.
        string key_global = "global_cache";
        string key_date = "date_cache";
        if (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue<Country[]>(key_countries, out Country[] values) &&
            (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue<Global>(key_global, out Global value) &&
              (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue<DateTime>(key_date, out DateTime date)))) // Verifica se há dados em cache.
        {
          var create = RestService.For<IGetRoot>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
          var result = await create.GetAsync(); // sou var result = create.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
          _logger.LogInformation(result.ToString());
          Global = result.Global;
          Countries = result.Countries;
          Date = result.Date;
          MemoryCache.Set(key_countries, Countries, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)); // Salva os dados em cache e define um tempo de expiração
          MemoryCache.Set(key_global, Global, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
          MemoryCache.Set(key_date, Date, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
        }
        else
        {
          Global = value;
          Countries = values;
          Date = date;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        _logger.LogInformation("Erro na requisição http: " + e.Message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: você atribuiu um valor que não existe! no `else` do seu código `value` e `date` não está declaro, se está confundindo porque esses valores deveria ter o seu próprio `if` e `else`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que suas variáveis estão em escopos/blocos diferentes, declare-as antes do `if-else` e corrija os `TryGetValue` retirando o tipo de dado após o parâmetro `out`.

```cs
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
Global value = null;
Country[] values = null;

if (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue<Country[]>(key_countries, out values) &&
    (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue<Global>(key_global, out value) &&
        (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue<DateTime>(key_date, out date)))) // Verifica se há dados em cache.
{
    var create = RestService.For<IGetRoot>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
    var result = await create.GetAsync(); // sou var result = create.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    _logger.LogInformation(result.ToString());
    Global = result.Global;
    Countries = result.Countries;
    Date = result.Date;
    MemoryCache.Set(key_countries, Countries, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)); // Salva os dados em cache e define um tempo de expiração
    MemoryCache.Set(key_global, Global, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    MemoryCache.Set(key_date, Date, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
}
else
{
    Global = value;
    Countries = values;
    Date = date;
}
```

Comment: DateTime não é anulável.

Comment: você tem razão. corrigido.

Comment: Na primeira vez que entra no site, a requisição é feita e os dados são armazenados em cache, para que, na segunda vez que entre no site, não precise fazer outra requisição. Porém está fazendo uma segunda requisição, porque sempre vai setar o Date como mínimo. E agora?

Comment: Isso é um problema que já existia antes da alteração que lhe sugeri, que foi para corrigir o erro de "Uso de variável não atribuída". Esse comportamento que você cita está relacionado à lógica que você adotou para fazer esse tipo de controle, para isso, sugiro que você faça uma revisão desse método.